# How to concatenate through a for loop R

Tags: r

Suppose I have this function to clean data

```
clean <- function(data, year, ecSec, tail = T, head = F){
  
  data1 <- data %>% 
    filter(year == year) %>% 
    filter(ciiu1 == ecSec) %>% 
    select(year, ruc, valueAdded, sales, totAssets, wages, materials, c_debtRatio)
  
  if(tail == T){
    
    list <- data1 %>% 
      filter_if(is.numeric, any_vars(. < quantile(., 0.01, na.rm=T))) %>% 
      select(ruc, year) %>% 
      unique()
    
    data2 <- data %>% 
      filter(! ruc %in% list$ruc & year == year)
    
    return(data2)
  }
  
  if(head ==T){
    list <- data2 %>% 
      filter_if(is.numeric, any_vars(. > quantile(., 0.99, na.rm = T))) %>% 
      select(ruc, year) %>% 
      unique()
    
    data3 <- data %>% 
      filter(! ruc %in% list$ruc & year == year)
    
    return(data3)
  }
  
}
```

It is supposed to cut the top and bottom 1% after filtering for `ciiu1` and `year`

So what I want to do is to first go through ciiu1 == A for year == 2012

`r1 <- clean(data, year = 2012, ecSec = "A")`

this will return a dataframe called `r1`. Then I will want to run:

`r2 <- clean(r1, year = 2013, ecSec = "A")`

and so on to cover all the ecSec ("A","C","F","G") for the 2012 - 2020 timespan

How can I do this with a for loop?

If possible how can I do this with a `foreach` loop?

I can't upload my whole data here, because is huge.

If needed can you tell me how can I get a smaller sample to upload here as a reproducible example?

Comment: Please confirm, that each clean function call actualy depends on the results of the prior clean function call. Your function returns the data variable filtered by the year, therefore once exectued for 2012 the clean function call for 2013 wont work since all 2013 data has already been removed

Comment: Can't replicate without an example. Anyway, here's an example of grouping by one variable and removing the top/bottom 1% for one variable using `dplyr` functions: `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% filter(between(Sepal.Length, quantile(Sepal.Length, .01), quantile(Sepal.Length, .99)))`

Comment: Rather than removing the data, wouldn't winsorization be better? Trying to exclude all observations that carry "outlying" values for specific variable(s) may oversimplify your dataset.